# Возврат из цикла (return)

Tags: c#, .net

```
class ChkNum {
    // Возвратить значение true, если значение
    // параметра х окажется простым числом.
    public bool IsPrime(int x) {
        if (x <= 1) return false;
        for (int i = 2; i <= x / i; i++)
            if ((x % i) == 0) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
class ParmDemo {
    static void Main() {
        ChkNum ob = new ChkNum();
        for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
            if (ob.IsPrime(i)) Console.WriteLine(i + " простое число.");
            else Console.WriteLine(i + " непростое число.");
    }
}
```

Когда i принимает значение 9, то из метода IsPrime возвращается значение true. Соответственно должна выполняться команда

```
Console.WriteLine(i + " простое число.");
```

Но выполняется

```
Console.WriteLine(i + " непростое число.");
```

Почему ?

Comment: но ведь 9 - это не простое число

Comment: Ошибка в классе ChkNum проверьте вычисления на отладчике, кстати если не секрет, что это за проект такой?

Comment: @pavel1787mego Gerbert Shildt C# 4.0

Comment: @Grundy Да, это не простое число, но по логике программы должен быть вывод на экран другая фраза. Пожалуйста, проверьте логику.

Comment: а с чего ты взял, что для 9 IsPrime возвращает true? у меня false возвращает

Comment: @Grundy У меня тоже false. И вывод - не простое.

Comment: @Grundy И у меня false, но смотря на код я считаю, что должно возвращаться true, а не false.

Comment: @foxhound потому что условие `if ((x % i) == 0) return false`; не выполняется для числа 9, соответственно выполняется следующий оператор, а следующий оператор return true.

Comment: _смотря на код я считаю, что должно возвращаться true, а не false._ - ты ошибаешься. для x=9 и i=3, условие `(x % i) == 0` вернет `true`, соответственно вся функция вернет `false`. Все правильно

Comment: @Grundy результат 9%3 равен 1. 1 не равен нулю, условие не верно. Что я не правильно понимаю ?

Comment: *результат 9%3 равен 1*: https://www.google.ru/search?q=9%3

Comment: @PetSerAl неждан :l

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev, 9 делится на 3 нацело, поэтому **остаток от деления** - 0. Что-то не пойму как 1 могло получиться

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev, А чем Вы руководствовались, когда 9%3=1 получили? Тогда и можно будет сказать в чем Вы ошибаетесь.

Comment: @foxhound невнимательность

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы квадраты простых чисел считались простыми (что за бред-то?), надо условие `i <= x` заменить на `i < x`.

Comment: Да там нормальное условие, посмотрите внимательно! `i <= x / i` Если умножить обе части на `i`, то окажется что мы вообще перебираем до корня из `x`

Comment: @Андрей, предлагаю внимательно прочитать ответ. И комментарии к вопросу.